# How to use magento declarative schema?

Tags: magento2.3, declarative-schema

**How to create table,alter table and drop the table using declarative schema??**

**If anyone have reference links or extension then please guide me.**

**I already referred below links.**

> [inchoo Blog](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/declarative-schema/)
>
> [dckap Blog](https://www.dckap.com/blog/declarative-schema-magento-2/)
>
> [AncutaIonela GitHub](https://github.com/AncutaIonela/module-declarative-schema)
>
> [victortodoran Githunb](http://%20https://github.com/victortodoran/module-declarative-schema)
>
> [yireo-training GitHub](https://github.com/yireo-training/magento2-example-declarative-schema)
>
> [bdcrops GitHub](https://github.com/bdcrops/module-declarative)

Answer (score 1):

To drop a column in declarative schema you need to delete the column from db_schema.xml file and regenerate the db_schema_whitelist.json file.

Follow the steps below:
1. Delete the desired column from the db_schema.xml file 
2. Run the command below

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendorname_Modulename
```

3.Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

The column will be dropped from the schema.

Answer (score 0):

**Check This Link**

> [Configure declarative schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html)
>
> [Declarative Schema in Magento 2.3](https://cedcommerce.com/blog/declarative-schema-in-magento-2-3/)
>
> [DECLARATIVE SCHEMA IN MAGENTO 2.3](https://www.dckap.com/blog/declarative-schema-magento-2/)
>
> [Declarative Schema in Magento 2.3](https://onilab.com/blog/declarative-schema-magento-2-3-and-higher/)

Comment: have you created any custom extension using Declarative Schema??

Comment: Yes............................

Comment: Have you dropped any column or full table using it ?

Comment: let me check...

Comment: ok.............